# How to hide horizontal and vertical guide lines for dart code in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, dart

I use Android Studio 3.4.1 for Flutter development with dart language and I want to remove these -not so useful- helping lines in dart pages, How can I do that in Android Studio Settings?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can enable/disable this by going to `Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter`. Then in the **Editor** section, unckeck **Show UI Guides for build methods**.